# Auto-complete support for kotlin in Eclipse-neon

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

I have imported a spring-boot + Kotlin project into Eclipse-Neon.

When I try to do an `auto-import` or a `tool-tip` help for definitions used inside the application, it does not work.

I have searched on and found this 
[link](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/eclipse-no-autocomplete-of-java-classes/1606) and [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11956) 
saying that no support is available.

Comment: other support like Cntrl+left-mouse-click to navigate seems to be unavailable!

Comment: Did you install the Kotlin plugin?

Comment: yes , Marketplace window is clearly showing "Kotlin plugin for Eclipse 0.8.2" "installed"  , Am i missing something?

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the error log?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and switch to IntelliJ Community edition if you think seriously about Kotlin development. IDE support for Kotlin is superb. Unfortunately IJ Community doesn't supports Spring development but with spring boot that has build in support for e.g. live reloading this shouldn't be an issue

Comment: @MikhailZarechenskiy no error but no auto-imports and no mouse click options to move around from one class location to another